# Black screen/No response after installing build-essential dkms and Guest Additions on VirtualBox (VM Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

On my PC where I have installed Manjaro I installed VirtualBox and I tried hosting `Ubuntu`.
After freshly creating the `Ubuntu 18` VM I updated it.
Then run this command:
`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms`
After that in the VirtualBox `Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD Image` and enabled `Shared Clipboard` and `Drag and Drop` to be `Bidirectional`. Then after it installed I powered off the VM and tried rebooting it but all I have now is a black screen. Then I proceeded to reboot the VM a few times. All I was getting is either a black screen or Ubuntu desktop totally freezer where I could even move the mouse cursor.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to make sure you have correct Display settings:

[image]

You have to have `VBoxSVGA` selected!